# Replace the name of data frame with specific character

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, character, rename

`"Dominance(DBH)"    "Uniform angle"   "CV(H)"`

The above is the names of a data frame, I want to replace the character "(" and ")" to "_"

`data%>%rename_at(vars(contains("\\(")),~str_replace(.,c("\\(","\\)"),"_"))`

The above command will present output but doesn't work(the name of data frame seem like before）

Comment: Try with `gsub('[()]', '_', .)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gsub` as follows:

```r
x <- c("Dominance(DBH)", "Uniform angle", "CV(H)")
output <- gsub("\\((.*?)\\)", "_\\1_", x)
output

[1] "Dominance_DBH_" "Uniform angle"  "CV_H_"
```